# how to have a different layout for a different model in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, view, model, controller

I have this model 'Comment' with controller 'CommentsController' and different views for 'add', 'edit', 'delete' functions that is being viewed on default.ctp layout. But I want to create another model which is a 'Login' model with 'LogInController' controller and different views for validation. I want this to be viewed of course on another layout that will be the interface of the login panel. But how can I create another layout for that? whenever I am viewing this log in view it is always appearing to the default.ctp layout.

Comment: Please make sure you check CakePHP's documentation before you post trivial questions like this one. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#layouts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your `logins_controller.php`, specify a different layout:

```
class LoginsController extends AppController {
   var $layout = 'login';
}
```

Then create `APP/View/Layouts/login.ctp` for your `login.ctp` html etc

Comment: that was quick and very well said. Thank You. I'll try it. :)

Comment: which cakephp version are you using btw? 1.x or 2.x? :o

Comment: cakePHP 2.1. is there changes??

Comment: its APP/View/Layouts/login.ctp in 2.x

Comment: @JohnMicahFernandezMiguel yeah, in 2.x it's `APP/View/Layouts/login.ctp`, I'm gonna edit my answer, sorry was assuming you were on 1.x

Comment: @tigrang was editing when you add that comment, thanks for that anyway :)

Comment: but in the code there's no problem?? okey thanks anyway I'm gonna try it now. ^_^

Comment: @JohnMicahFernandezMiguel You should probably try that first and confirm it's working before accepting :)

Comment: You can also set it using `$this->layout = 'login'` for individual methods, allowing you to overwrite as needed.